# How do entangled states increase computational space for quantum computers compared when only using product states?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

My question is:

**n-qubit product state.**
$$|\psi\rangle=(a_1|0\rangle+a_2|1\rangle)\otimes(b_1|0\rangle+b_2|1\rangle)\otimes \cdots$$

**n-qubit Entangled state**

$$|\psi\rangle=(a_1|000\cdots000\rangle)+(a_2|000\cdots001\rangle)+(a_3|000\cdots010\rangle) \cdots$$

In the entangled states there are $2^n$ different amplitudes which I understand why.
My problem lies in if we multiply out the product states we will also get $2^n$ amplitudes (while the correct answer is $2N$) (correct me if i am incorrect)

**if we considered it to be three qubits then it will be** 
$$(a_1|0\rangle+a_2|1\rangle)\otimes(a_3|0\rangle+a_4|1\rangle)\otimes(a_5|0\rangle+a_6|1\rangle) $$

**if we multiply them together it will be:** 
$$a_1a_3a_5|000\rangle+a_1a_3a_6|001\rangle+a_1a_4a_6|011\rangle+a_1a_4a_5|010\rangle+a_2a_4a_6|111\rangle+a_2a_4a_5|110\rangle+a_2a_3a_5|100\rangle+a_2a_3a_6|101\rangle$$

**which also gives the same 3 qubit arrangements as a general entangled qubit state**
$$a_1|000\rangle+a_2|001\rangle+a_3|010\rangle+a_4|100\rangle+a_5|110\rangle+a_6|101\rangle+a_7|111\rangle+a_8|011\rangle$$

**So where is the difference?**
If I made any mistake along the way please point it out for me.
**This is an assumption i made in an online course on quantum computation and i didnt quite understand what made entangled states increase computational space to 2^n and when using product states computational states was only 2N** 
Consider that this is my main concern.
I am sorry if its a silly question as i am still a beginner in the field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is quantum entanglement so important in the context of quantum computation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47951/)

Comment: I think it's not clear what you are asking exactly. One is a product state ($2N=6$ parameters for $N=3$), the other is a generic state in the 8-qubit Hilbert space ($2^N=8$ parameters).

Comment: Also, the question is the title seems to be different from the one in the body.

Comment: To make an analogy with simpler things, what you're asking is something like: If you take an integer $3$ and express it as $3.0000000...$, it looks just like a real number. So what is the difference between integers and real numbers? Not all real numbers can be expressed as integers. Not all states $a_1$|000⟩+$a_2$|001⟩+$a_3$|010⟩ +$a_4$|100⟩+$a_5$|110⟩+$a_6$|101⟩+$a_7$|111⟩+$a_8$|011⟩ can be represented as a product state.

Comment: @PeterShor so does that make any difference in the computational space available?

Comment: @fqq i have modified the title to my exact question, what i have written in the body was an assumption i made in an online course on quantum computation and i didnt quite understand what made entangled states increase computational space to 2^n and when using product states computational states was only 2N

Comment: There’s not much to say. The first state you wrote down has $2N$ parameters you can adjust, so it stores at most $2N$ compels numbers worth of information. It doesn’t matter if you write it in a complicated way so that it is the sum of an exponentially large number of terms, it can still be described by a small amount of information. The second state you wrote down can’t be.

Comment: Another way to say this is that there exist numbers $a_1,...,a_8$ that cannot be written as products of $a_1,...,a_6$ as you’ve written. So the second state is more general. This is what professor Shor was trying to get at with his real/natural number example. Every natural number can be written as a real number, but that just proves natural number are a SUBSET of the reals, not that natural numbers are the same as the reals.

Comment: @JahanClaes so what you mean is that even if i expand the first state i wrote it would still only have 2N complex numbers worth of information am i correct?

Comment: @yousefelbrolosy Exactly! Just like if you write your natural numbers as 2.00000000000000000... it doesn't mean they take more information to describe, even if you write them in a way that takes a lot of information to store/display!

Comment: @JahanClaes Perfect! Thank you so muchh!!

Comment: Thanks to all!! @PeterShor, JahanClaes, fqq, exp ikx

Comment: @JahanClaes just one last trivial question, is a1|000⟩+a2|001⟩+a3|010⟩+a4|100⟩+a5|110⟩+a6|101⟩+a7|111⟩+a8|011⟩ a generic entangled state correct? Can you explain what is meant by generic?

Comment: or like how is it created

Comment: It’s the most general state that three qubits can be in. As for how to create one: it’s hard! You start with some simple to create state, then do stuff to it (apply unitary Gates) until it looks like the state you want. What you need to do will depend on the state you want!

Comment: just one last thing to make sure, correct me if i am wrong, the first product state with 6 coefficients is a **generic product state** while the second one with 8 coefficients is a **generic entangled state**?@JahanClaes